# How to access secret manager with boto3 and rds-data

Tags: python, boto3, aws-secrets-manager, chalice, aws-rds-data-service

In a [chalice](https://aws.github.io/chalice/index.html) route, I'm using boto3 to execute queries against my RDS Aurora Serverless DB cluster. This works as expected locally (`$ chalice local`) but when deployed on Lamdba I receive the error: `An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the ExecuteStatement operation: Failed to fetch secret arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2...`

I've updated a variety of policies between the VPC following the instructions here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html?icmpid=docs_lambda_help.

`boto3.client('rds-data').execute_statement( resourceArn = cluster_arn,  secretArn = secret_arn,  database = 'XXX',  sql = sql, # sql string )`

Comment: Lambda function in VPC does not have access to internet, thus it will not access secret manager. Have you ensured access using NAT gateway or interface endpoints?

Comment: I have configured both a private and public subnet for my VPC, created a couple new route tables, created the NAT and internet gateway, and then attached the lambda to the private VPC. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/